# Mysql workbench loses connection after restarting computer

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed Mysql server and mysql workbench and have successfully used mysql workbench to work with my databases. I used it and have since then closed the program and shut off my computer. Now when I click on my connection, it shows a server status screen and says 'no connection'. I get error message 10061  could not connect server may not be running. This is the second time this happened to me and I find that reinstalling mysql fixes this. The problem is I cannot reinstall every time I need to use mysql workbench. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you connect to mysql in any other way? Are you sure this is related to workbench? Try connecting to mysql via terminal or other database management program to see if you get the same results.

Comment: Is your server actually running after you started your machine again?

Comment: My guess would be no. But I did reinstall the server and checked the box that turns on the server when starting up the computer. I had it unchecked at first.